# Is this alternate answer right?

Tags: general-topology, alternative-proof

This is really basic, but I don't want to get the fundamentals wrong.

> Show that if $A$ is closed in $Y$ and $Y$ is closed in $X$, then $A$ is closed in $X$.

The solution uses subspaces (which I understand and agree),  but I did this instead.

$A$ is closed in $Y$, so $Y - A$ is open in $Y$. Also $X - Y$ is open in $X$, so $(X - Y)  \cup (Y - A) = A^c$ is open in $X$.

Comment: $X-Y \cup Y-A$ is horribly ambiguous. You _must_ use parentheses here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you haven't shown is why $Y-A$ is open **in $X$**; since you want to claim that $A$ is closed in $X$.

Why is this true?

Comment: So does this mean this method isn't likely going to lead anywhere? I can't justify why $Y - A$ might be open in $X$. All I could do is $Y - A = Y \cap O$ for some open set in $X$.

Comment: Well, the only way I can think of justifying that is essentially showing that $A$ is closed, and concluding that $O$ can be taken as $X-A$.

Comment: So basically the book's answer...

Comment: Yes. Basically the book's answer.